# SonarQube Cobol Plugin parse error

Tags: sonarqube, cobol, sonarqube-4.5

In a working cobol program JCS00008.cob (attached at the end), I have some custom Macro calls (such as &AQENVIAR, &AQERROR and &AQERRORV).
I receive a parsing error on statment &AQENVIAR (at lines 323, 359, 416) like this:

```
ERROR c.s.cobol.squid.CobolAstScanner - Unable to parse COBOL source file : C:\sonar-test\JCS00008.cob at line 323
 ...
 ...
 Parse error at line 323:
  318:  NUM-CONDICION-ADICIONAL OF TC07002I
  319:  MOVE '0001' TO COD-EMPRESA OF TC07002I
  320:  MOVE WKS-SPORTELL TO COD-CENTRO OF TC07002I .
  321:  MOVE SPACES TO NOMBRE OF TC07002I .
  322:  MOVE SPACES TO COD-TIPO-CENTRO OF TC07002I .
  323:  & AQENVIAR ( TCS07002 INPUT-TXN-TCS07002
       ^
  324:  OUTPUT-TXN-TCS07002 ERROR-AREA )
```

Doing some trial modifying the cobol file, it seams the reason why I don't get the same error also on &AQERROR and &AQERRORV (at lines 267, 303, 333, 366, 389) is because those macro are wrapped in an if/else statment.

Environment:

- Sonarqube Version: 4.5.4
- Cobol Plugin Version: 2.7 / 2.8

Here the whole cobol program JCS00008.cob:

```html
      ****************************************************************
      **                                                            **
      **           BNL IT 2001                                      **
      **                                                            **
      **                                                            **
      ****************************************************************
      **                                                            **
      **  MODULE NAME:    XXXXXXXX                                  **
      **                                                            **
      **  DATE GENERATED: XXXXXX  XX/XX/XXXX                        **
      **                                                            **
      **  BY USER:                                                  **
      **                                                            **
      **  DESIGNER:                                                 **
      **                                                            **
      **  PROGRAMMER:                                               **
      **                                                            **
      **                                                            **
      **  DESCRIPTION                                               **
      **                                                            **
      **                                                            **
      **                                                            **
      ****************************************************************

       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. JCS00008.
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.

       DATA DIVISION.

       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

      ****************************************************************
      **              VARIABILI DI ARCHITETTURA                     **
      ****************************************************************
       01  AH-VARIABLES.
           05 AH-PROGRAMA-PREVIO      PIC X(8).
           05 AH-LONGITUD-PREVIA      PIC S9(9)  COMP-3.
           05 FILLER                  PIC 9 VALUE 0.
               88 AH-ERROR-SERVI-CONTROL-ARQ VALUE 0.
               88 AH-ERROR-SERVI-CONTROL-APL VALUE 1.
       01  FND-SEVERITY-OK           PIC S9(4) COMP VALUE 0.
       01  FND-SEVERITY-WARNING      PIC S9(4) COMP VALUE 4.
       01  FND-SEVERITY-ERROR        PIC S9(4) COMP VALUE 8.
       01  FND-SEVERITY-FATAL        PIC S9(4) COMP VALUE 16.
       01  LOG-APPL-DATA             PIC X(80) VALUE SPACES.
      ***
      ****************************************************************
      ** COPY ERRORI ARCHITETTURA                                   **
      ****************************************************************
      *
       COPY AHNUMERR.
      *
      ****************************************************************
      ** COPY DI ERRORE DB2                                         **
      ****************************************************************
      *
      *COPY ERRSQLCO.

      *    EXEC SQL
      *        INCLUDE SQLCA
      *    END-EXEC.
      *
      ****************************************************************
      ** COPY DEL PROGRAMMATORE                                     **
      ****************************************************************
           COPY JCG01RC.
      *
      ****************************************************************
      **              VARIABILI DEL PROGRAMMATORE                   **
      ****************************************************************
       01  JCZRIC3T                  PIC X(8) VALUE 'JCZRIC3T'.
       01  NKS17272                  PIC X(8) VALUE 'NKS17272'.
       01  TCS07002                  PIC X(8) VALUE 'TCS07002'.
       01  TCS08002                  PIC X(8) VALUE 'TCS08002'.
       01  IND                       PIC 9(3) COMP-3 VALUE 0.
       01  WKS-CONTO                 PIC X(6).
       01  WKS-SPORTELL              PIC X(4).
      *
       01  WS-NUM-ERR                PIC S9(8) COMP VALUE 0.
      *
      * AREA RELATIVA ALLA GESTIONE DEGLI ERRORI                        02100000
           COPY  NXERR01.                                               02110000
      *
       01  INPUT-TXN-NK17272.
          COPY NK17272I.

       01  OUTPUT-TXN-NK17272.
          COPY NK17272O.
      **** COPY AREA I/O COMPONENTE 'ESISTENZA SPORTELLO'
       01 INPUT-TXN-TCS07002.
           COPY TC07002I.
       01 OUTPUT-TXN-TCS07002.
           COPY TC07002O.

      **** COPY AREA I/O COMPONENTE 'AREA TERRITORIALE'
       01 INPUT-TXN-TCS08002.
           COPY TC08002I.
       01 OUTPUT-TXN-TCS08002.
           COPY TC08002O.
      ****************************************************************
      **              LITERAL DEL PROGRAMMATORE                     **
      ****************************************************************
       01  LT-CONSTANT.
          05 LT-TRUE              PIC 9         VALUE 1.

      ***********************************************************
      * INSERIRE IL NOME DEL PROGRAMMA PRESENTE NELLA PROGRAM-ID*
      ***********************************************************
           05 LT-PROGRAM-NAME      PIC X(08)     VALUE 'JCS00008'.
      *
      ****************************************************************
      ** INCLUDE TABELLE DB2                                        **
      ****************************************************************
      *
       LINKAGE SECTION.
      *
       01 DFHCOMMAREA                 PIC X.
       01 DFHEIBLK                    PIC X.
      *
      ****************************************************************
      ** AREA DE CONTEXTO                                           **
      ****************************************************************
       01 CONTEXT-AREA.
          COPY AHCONTEX.

      ****************************************************************
      ** INPUT AND OUTPUT MESSAGE DATA                              **
      ****************************************************************
       01  INPUT-TXN.
          COPY JC00008I.

       01  OUTPUT-TXN.
          COPY JC00008O.

      ****************************************************************
      ** AREA DE ERRORES                                            **
      ****************************************************************
       01 ERROR-AREA.
          COPY AHERROR.

       PROCEDURE DIVISION USING DFHEIBLK
                                DFHCOMMAREA
                                CONTEXT-AREA
                                INPUT-TXN
                                OUTPUT-TXN
                                ERROR-AREA.

      **********************************************
      * LABEL DA NON TOGLIERE SERVE COME PUNTATORE *
      * AL PREPROCESSORE                           *
      **********************************************
      * START CODE PROCEDURE

           PERFORM 0001-ARCH-HOUSEKEEPING.

           PERFORM 0010-APPL-CODE.

           PERFORM 0009-ARCH-WRAPUP.


      ****************************************************************
      **     PROCEDURE DIVISION INITIALIZATION                      **
      ****************************************************************
       0001-ARCH-HOUSEKEEPING.

           INITIALIZE AH-VARIABLES
                      OUTPUT-TXN.

           MOVE AH-PROGRAM-NAME     TO AH-PROGRAMA-PREVIO.
           MOVE LT-PROGRAM-NAME     TO AH-PROGRAM-NAME.

      ****************************************************************
      ** - CODICE APPLICATIVO                                       **
      ****************************************************************
       0010-APPL-CODE.

           PERFORM A1000-HOUSEKEEPING.
           PERFORM A2000-PROCESS.
           PERFORM A3000-WRAP-UP.

      ****************************************************************
      ** - INIZIALIZZAZIONE DI VARIABILI APPLICATIVE                **
      ****************************************************************
       A1000-HOUSEKEEPING.
      *
           INITIALIZE JC00008O.
TOGLI *    MOVE '06319'             TO   JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CFILI-CC.
TOGLI *    MOVE '20070125'          TO   JCA-BO-DET-SPO-DATA-PRE.
TOGLI *    MOVE '  '                TO   JCA-BO-DET-SPO-PAG-UPDW.
TOGLI *    MOVE '  '                TO   JCA-BO-DET-SPO-PAG-CORR.
      *
      ****************************************************************
      * - GESTISCE LA LOGICA APPLICATIVA DEL COMPONENTE             **
      ****************************************************************
       A2000-PROCESS.
      *
           PERFORM A2001-CONTR-SPO.
      *
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCS00008: PRIMA CHIAMATA: '
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCS00008: AREA INPUT:   '
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CFILI-CC ' JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CFILI-CC.
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCA-BO-DET-SPO-DATA-PRE ' JCA-BO-DET-SPO-DATA-PRE.
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCA-BO-DET-SPO-PAG-UPDW ' JCA-BO-DET-SPO-PAG-UPDW.
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCA-BO-DET-SPO-PAG-CORR ' JCA-BO-DET-SPO-PAG-CORR.
      *
           CALL JCZRIC3T       USING
                               DFHEIBLK
                               DFHCOMMAREA
                               INPUT-TXN
                               OUTPUT-TXN.
      *
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCS00008: DOPO CHIAMATA: '
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCS00008: AREA OUTPUT:   '
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CDOPE-OUT '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CDOPE-OUT(1) ' '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CDOPE-OUT(2) ' '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CDOPE-OUT(3) ' '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CDOPE-OUT(4) ' '.
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCA-BO-DET-SPO-IMPO-OUT '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-IMPO-OUT(1) ' '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-IMPO-OUT(2) ' '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-IMPO-OUT(3) ' '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-IMPO-OUT(4) ' ' .
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCA-BO-DET-SPO-NR-PREN-OUT '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-NR-PREN-OUT(1) ' '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-NR-PREN-OUT(2) ' '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-NR-PREN-OUT(3) ' '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-NR-PREN-OUT(4) ' ' .
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CCFIL-OUT '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CCFIL-OUT(1) ' '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CCFIL-OUT(2) ' '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CCFIL-OUT(3) ' '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CCFIL-OUT(4) ' ' .
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CONTO-OUT '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CONTO-OUT(1) ' '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CONTO-OUT(2) ' '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CONTO-OUT(3) ' '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CONTO-OUT(4) ' ' .
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCA-BO-DET-SPO-NOPER-OUT '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-NOPER-OUT(1) ' '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-NOPER-OUT(2) ' '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-NOPER-OUT(3) ' '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-NOPER-OUT(4) ' ' .
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCA-BO-DET-SPO-INTESTA-OUT '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-INTESTA-OUT(1) ' '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-INTESTA-OUT(2) ' '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-INTESTA-OUT(3) ' '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-INTESTA-OUT(4) ' ' .
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCA-BO-DET-SPO-QTA-PREN-OUT '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-QTA-PREN-OUT.
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCA-BO-DET-SPO-IMPO-TOT-OUT '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-IMPO-TOT-OUT.
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCA-BO-DET-SPO-FDATI '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-FDATI.
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCA-BO-DET-SPO-PAGIN '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-PAGIN.
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCA-BO-DET-SPO-MESG-COD-KO '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-MESG-COD-KO.
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCA-BO-DET-SPO-MESG-DESCR-KO '
TOGLI *             JCA-BO-DET-SPO-MESG-DESCR-KO.
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'JCA-BO-DET-SPO-MESG-OK ' JCA-BO-DET-SPO-MESG-OK.
      *
           IF  JCA-BO-DET-SPO-MESG-OK NOT EQUAL 'OK'
              MOVE JCA-BO-DET-SPO-MESG-COD-KO    TO   WS-NUM-ERR
              MOVE JCA-BO-DET-SPO-MESG-DESCR-KO  TO   NX1-DESCRIZIONE
              &AQERRORV(ERROR,WS-NUM-ERR,NXERR01,
                        JCA-BO-DET-SPO-MESG-DESCR-KO)
           END-IF.
      *
PROVA      PERFORM A2010-RIC-INTESTATARIO
              VARYING IND FROM    1 BY 1
              UNTIL   IND GREATER JCA-BO-DET-SPO-QTA-PREN-OUT.
      *
      ****************************************************************
      * - GESTISCE LA LOGICA APPLICATIVA DEL COMPONENTE             **
      ****************************************************************
       A2001-CONTR-SPO.
      *
           MOVE JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CFILI-CC(2:4)  TO WKS-SPORTELL
      *
      *    DISPLAY ' AQBF-COD-CENTRO = ' AQBF-COD-CENTRO
      *
      *    MOVE '1900' TO AQBF-COD-CENTRO
      *
           IF AQBF-COD-CENTRO    NOT = JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CFILI-CC (2:4)
              MOVE AQBF-COD-CENTRO     TO WKS-SPORTELL
              PERFORM S5000-CL-TCS07002 THRU S5000-CL-TCS07002-EX
CANC  *       DISPLAY 'COD-TIPO-CENTRO OF OUTPUT-TXN-TCS07002 (1) ='
CANC  *       COD-TIPO-CENTRO OF OUTPUT-TXN-TCS07002 (1)
              IF COD-TIPO-CENTRO OF OUTPUT-TXN-TCS07002 (1) = '00'
                 MOVE JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CFILI-CC(2:4) TO WKS-SPORTELL
      *          DISPLAY 'WKS-SPORTELLO 1= ' WKS-SPORTELL

                 PERFORM S5000-CL-TCS08002 THRU S5000-CL-TCS08002-EX
                 PERFORM S5100-CL-ESITO-OPE THRU S5100-CL-ESITO-OPE-EX
              ELSE
                 MOVE 'SPORTELLO OPERANTE NON ABILITATO'
                                    TO JCA-BO-DET-SPO-MESG-DESCR-KO
                                       NX1-DESCRIZIONE
                 MOVE 55603         TO JCA-BO-DET-SPO-MESG-COD-KO
                                       WS-NUM-ERR
                 &AQERRORV(ERROR,WS-NUM-ERR,NXERR01,
                           JCA-BO-DET-SPO-MESG-DESCR-KO)
              END-IF
           END-IF.
      ****************************************************************
      * - CONTROLLO SPORTELLO                                       **
      ****************************************************************
       S5000-CL-TCS07002.
           INITIALIZE INPUT-TXN-TCS07002
                      OUTPUT-TXN-TCS07002.
      *
           MOVE 'V'          TO ACC-SERV                OF TC07002I
           MOVE  1           TO NUM-REGE                OF TC07002I
           MOVE '0'          TO IND-TIPO-LIS            OF TC07002I
           MOVE  1           TO NUM-CLAVE               OF TC07002I
           MOVE ZEROES       TO NUM-CONDICION-ADICIONAL OF TC07002I
           MOVE '0001'       TO COD-EMPRESA             OF TC07002I
           MOVE WKS-SPORTELL TO COD-CENTRO              OF TC07002I.
           MOVE SPACES       TO NOMBRE                  OF TC07002I.
           MOVE SPACES       TO COD-TIPO-CENTRO         OF TC07002I.
           &AQENVIAR(TCS07002,INPUT-TXN-TCS07002,
                                    OUTPUT-TXN-TCS07002,ERROR-AREA)
      *     DISPLAY 'ERROR-AREA= ' ERROR-AREA
      *     DISPLAY ' FNDSEVEREERRORCODE = ' FNDSEVEREERRORCODE
      *     DISPLAY ' FNDERRORMSGAREA   = 'FNDERRORMSGAREA
      *     IF AH-SEVERE-ERROR
      *        &AQERROR(ERROR, AH-ERROR-MSG-NUM, AH-ERROR-MSG-AREA)
      *     END-IF

            IF NOT AH-SEVERE-OK
               &AQERROR(ERROR, AH-ERROR-MSG-NUM, AH-ERROR-MSG-AREA)
            END-IF.
      *
       S5000-CL-TCS07002-EX.
           EXIT.
      *
      ****************************************************************
      ***                                                       ******
      ****************************************************************
       S5000-CL-TCS08002.
      *
           INITIALIZE INPUT-TXN-TCS08002
                      OUTPUT-TXN-TCS08002.

            MOVE '0001'
              TO COD-EMPRESA        OF INPUT-TXN-TCS08002.
            MOVE 'V'
              TO ACC-SERV           OF INPUT-TXN-TCS08002.
            MOVE 1
              TO NUM-REGE           OF INPUT-TXN-TCS08002.
            MOVE 1
              TO NUM-CLAVE          OF INPUT-TXN-TCS08002.
            MOVE WKS-SPORTELL
              TO COD-CENTRO         OF INPUT-TXN-TCS08002.
            MOVE '01'
              TO COD-ESTRUC-JERARQ  OF INPUT-TXN-TCS08002.
            &AQENVIAR(TCS08002,INPUT-TXN-TCS08002,OUTPUT-TXN-TCS08002,
                      ERROR-AREA)
      *     DISPLAY 'ERROR-AREA= ' ERROR-AREA
      *     DISPLAY ' FNDSEVEREERRORCODE = ' FNDSEVEREERRORCODE
      *     DISPLAY ' FNDERRORMSGAREA   = 'FNDERRORMSGAREA

           IF NOT AH-SEVERE-OK
              &AQERROR(ERROR, AH-ERROR-MSG-NUM, AH-ERROR-MSG-AREA)
           END-IF.

       S5000-CL-TCS08002-EX.
           EXIT.
      *************************************************************
       S5100-CL-ESITO-OPE.

      *
CANC  *    DISPLAY ' CODIGO-CENTRO-2 OF OUTPUT-TXN-TCS08002(1)= '
CANC  *    CODIGO-CENTRO-2 OF OUTPUT-TXN-TCS08002(1)
      *
      *    DISPLAY 'AQBF-COD-CENTRO ======' AQBF-COD-CENTRO
      *
      *    IF CODIGO-CENTRO-2 OF OUTPUT-TXN-TCS08002(1)
      *                       NOT = JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CFILI-CC (2:4)
           IF CODIGO-CENTRO-2 OF OUTPUT-TXN-TCS08002(1)
                              NOT = AQBF-COD-CENTRO
              MOVE 'SPORTELLO OPERANTE NON ABILITATO'
                                TO JCA-BO-DET-SPO-MESG-DESCR-KO
                                   NX1-DESCRIZIONE
              MOVE 55603        TO  JCA-BO-DET-SPO-MESG-COD-KO
                                    WS-NUM-ERR
                 &AQERRORV(ERROR,WS-NUM-ERR,NXERR01,
                           JCA-BO-DET-SPO-MESG-DESCR-KO)
           ELSE
      ****>>> SALVO L'AREA TERRITORIALE PER I CONTROLLI DI CONGRUENZA
      ***    MOVE CODIGO-CENTRO-2 OF OUTPUT-TXN-TCS08002(1)
      ***                         TO APPO-SPO-AT
           CONTINUE
           END-IF.

       S5100-CL-ESITO-OPE-EX.
           EXIT.
      ****************************************************************
      * - RICERCA INTESTATARIO C/C SU ACCORDI                       **
      ****************************************************************
       A2010-RIC-INTESTATARIO.
           INITIALIZE                        INPUT-TXN-NK17272
                                             OUTPUT-TXN-NK17272.
      *
           MOVE '0001'                  TO   COD-EMPRESA   OF NK17272I.
           MOVE JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CCFIL-OUT (IND)
                                        TO   COD-SPORTELLO OF NK17272I.
           MOVE JCA-BO-DET-SPO-CONTO-OUT (IND)
                                        TO   WKS-CONTO.
           MOVE WKS-CONTO               TO   COD-CONTO     OF NK17272I.
      *
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'INPUT: ' INPUT-TXN-NK17272.
      *
           &AQENVIAR(NKS17272,INPUT-TXN-NK17272,OUTPUT-TXN-NK17272).
      *
TOGLI *    DISPLAY 'OUTPUT: ' OUTPUT-TXN-NK17272.
      *
           IF NOT AH-SEVERE-OK
              MOVE ALL '*'         TO   JCA-BO-DET-SPO-INTESTA-OUT(IND)
      *       DISPLAY 'ERRORE CHIAMATA ACCORDI'
      *       DISPLAY 'ERROR-AREA        ' ERROR-AREA
      *       DISPLAY 'FNDABENDCODE      ' FNDABENDCODE
      *       DISPLAY 'FNDERRORAPPLTYPE  ' FNDERRORAPPLTYPE
      *       DISPLAY 'FNDERRORTYPECODE  ' FNDERRORTYPECODE
      *       DISPLAY 'FNDERRORTAGDATA   ' FNDERRORTAGDATA
      *       DISPLAY 'FNDERRORMSGNUM    ' FNDERRORMSGNUM
      *       DISPLAY 'FNDERRORMSGAREA   ' FNDERRORMSGAREA
      *       DISPLAY 'FNDLOADIMAGENAME  ' FNDLOADIMAGENAME
      *       DISPLAY 'FNDDEPMSGNUM      ' FNDDEPMSGNUM
      *       DISPLAY 'FNDSEVEREERRORCODE' FNDSEVEREERRORCODE
           ELSE
              MOVE DENOM-SOCIALE   TO   JCA-BO-DET-SPO-INTESTA-OUT(IND)
           END-IF.
      *
      ****************************************************************
      * - VALORIZZAZIONE DELL'OUTPUT MESSAGGE                       **
      *   EVENTUALI CONTROLLI PRIMA DELLA ATTIVAZIONE DELLA ROUTINE **
      ****************************************************************
       A3000-WRAP-UP.

      ****************************************************************
      ** - VIENE GESTITA LA FINE DELL'ELABORAZIONE                  **
      ****************************************************************
       0009-ARCH-WRAPUP.

           IF  AH-PROGRAM-NAME = APPL-PROGRAM-ID OF CONTEXT-AREA
              MOVE LENGTH OF OUTPUT-TXN
                          TO OUTPUT-TXN-LEN OF CONTEXT-AREA
           END-IF.

           MOVE AH-PROGRAMA-PREVIO  TO AH-PROGRAM-NAME

           GOBACK.
      *
       00091-RAD-MANAGEMENT.
      ******************************************************************
      *  00091-RAD-MANAGEMENT                                          *
      *  VIENE REALIZZATA LA SCRITTURA DEL DAL ATTRAVERSO LA CHIAMATA  *
      *  AL MODULO AH0500 CHE AL SUO INTERNO ESEGUIRA' UN CICLO DI     *
      *  QUANTE SONO LE RIGHE PRESENTI NELL'OCCURS DELL'AREA DI CONTEST*
      *  PRECEDENTEMENTE VALORIZZATE DAL MODULO AH0501                 *
      ******************************************************************

      *     CALL LT-MODULO-RAD  USING
      *                         DFHEIBLK
      *                         DFHCOMMAREA
      *                         CONTEXT-AREA
      *                         INPUT-TXN
      *                         OUTPUT-TXN
      *                         ERROR-AREA.
      *
      *    IF AH-SEVERE-ERROR OF ERROR-AREA
      *        PERFORM 00000-GESTION-ERROR
      *    END-IF
      *    .
       00000-GESTION-ERROR.
      ******************************************************************
      *   00000-GESTION-ERROR.                                         *
      *   PARAGRAFO DI GESTIONE ERRORE                                 *
      *   QUESTO PARAGRAFO E' CHIAMATO DALLA MACRO AQERROR             *
      ******************************************************************
           MOVE AH-PROGRAM-NAME TO AH-LOAD-IMAGE-NAME   OF ERROR-AREA
      *    IF AH-ERROR-DB2                              OF ERROR-AREA
      *       MOVE SQLCA        TO AH-DEP-MSG-AREA      OF ERROR-AREA
      *       MOVE SQLCODE      TO AH-DEP-MSG-NUM       OF ERROR-AREA
      *       SET AH-ERROR-TYPE-SQL OF ERROR-AREA    TO TRUE
      *    END-IF
           PERFORM 0009-ARCH-WRAPUP.
      *
```

Comment: COBOL does not have Macros. So whatever you are parsing the COBOL with knows nothing about the & which prefixes your macros. End of that story. Are you able to customise the parser? You'll need to either do that (or get it done for you) or "expand" the macros so that they are entirely COBOL source.

Comment: You should contact SonarSource commercial support.